# Delphi compiler: Compilation time grows non-linear with the amount of code

Tags: performance, parsing, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a project that has 188200 lines  (code size: 5.2MB) that builds in 4.0 sec.

Another project that is 4.8x larger (900900 lines, code size 22MB) compiles in 70.8 sec (similar speed on 64/32bit compiler).

Since the Delphi compiler parses the code in one step, why the compilation speed is not linear (or close to linear) with the amount of code?
70sec is quite far away from [the speed promised by Embarcadero](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/feel-the-lightning-speed-of-the-delphi-compiler-for-maximum-productivity/) (5 sec).

---

Using Delphi Sydney (that is v10.4.1 for those like me that lost track of which Delphi is which).

CPU: AMD FX 4GHz 8cores
RAM: 32GB (fast ram)
SSD: Samsung 840EVO
No antivirus (except Windows Defender)
Everything compiles in one code. The other 7 cores are free.

Comment: Most of the algorithms are not O(n) it the compilers.

Comment: Do you have cyclic unit dependencies in any of these projects?

Comment: It depends also on the performance of your computer. Are you using HDD or SSD? Do you have 16GB or more RAM? Do you have an anti-virus active? Not all HDD not all SSD are equals, speed vary a lot.

Comment: Depends on your code.

Comment: Core. You mean core, not "one code". Are there even compilers that are able to parallelize the process?

Comment: @AmigoJack [Parallel GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ParallelGcc)

Comment: In regards to cyclic unit dependencies I would note Model Maker Code Explorer (MMX)  has a Unit Dependency Analyzer. https://www.mmx-delphi.de/articles/unit-dependency-analyzer/  MMX is maintained by Uwe Raabe these days and is available for free.

Comment: Based on my experience Delphi compiler isn't the problem but its linker can be. For instance if you have two projects with roughly similar amount of code and in first project all that code is in a few large units and in second projects all that code is spread in many smaller units the compilation time itself won't differ much between the two projects but linking time will be much longer on for second project that is for first. Yes that hold even if doing full rebuild. So don't shove everything in its own unit.

Comment: @SilverWarior - I like how things work in the real world: half of the planet (especially the C++ guys) scream that each small snippet of code should be in its own class and each class in its own unit. But then, the other half screams: don't do it; it will ruin your compile time :) :)

Comment: @Gravity The reality is that there is no perfect solution that would work best in all scenarios. So when I said " don't shove everything in its own unit" I didn't mean that you should shove everything in one bug unit. But instead I just wanted for you to look back at your code and decide whether it might be better to merge some units together or not. No one could tell you what could be put in same unit and what not except yourself. You know your code and therefore you have best chance for making right decision that would work best in your scenario.

Comment: @Gravity Any way you are complaining about the fact that compiling 900K lines of code in Delphi takes you 70 seconds. I wonder what will those C++ guys sad about that. From what I know in most C++ compilers that could take about 30 minutes if not even more. So until it remains like this I will be choosing Delphi over any other programming language.

Comment: @Gravity In fact back in the days I started learning programming in C++ where on my old 100 Mhz AMD K5 computer it took whole two minutes to compile simple "Hello world" console application. But once I installed Delphi on that same computer I was amazed that I could build a complex GUI based applications in less time than that. To tell you the truth before I stumbled on Delphi I was actually thinking about gutting my desire to learn programming because waiting about 2 mins for slightest change made to code was simply to hard.

Comment: @SilverWarior. "I wonder what will those C++ guys" - You are right (+1), but I don't care about them. Let them struggle. It was THEIR choice to use C++ over Delphi :) I was "over the fence". I had to work with C++ for over 2.5 years. Any C/++ compiler is simply a snail. No mater how easy C//++ let you shoot yourself into the foot (abuse pointers, etc), C/++ simply remains pathetic and counterproductive. C++ guys will never admit it though.

Comment: @Gravity What I love about Delphi is that if you are insistent it will let you shot yourself into the foot just as C++ will. Yes you can go play with pointers and pointer math in Delphi if you wish so. Heck you can do even something that many C++ compilers won't let you do. You can go and insert assembly code directly into your application source code. And while Delphi will try to warn you about bad practices that you use in your code it will not do any checking on the inserted ASM code. So in a way Delphi will allow you to shoot something more important than just your foot.

Comment: "What I love about Delphi is that if you are insistent" True :)

Comment: @SilverWarior-https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/427-pointers-are-dangerous/